# How do I find the location of a "vector subscript out of range" error? C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

I am quite new to coding. I know what "vector subscript out of range" means, how it occures and how to fix it. But I have many many vectors in my code and often get this error. But when this error hits I always get this error box you all know. And it says "Hit retry to debug your application". And when I click it it brings me to line 1731 in the "vector" file. But how do I get to the point (the line or the file) in my code, where I created this error???

I tried using the Debug-Navigation in VisualStudio to move back and forth to get to my code. But this doesn't work. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the call-stack?

Comment: There will be buttons somewhere for the debugger to move "up" and "down" the call stack, which you can use until you are at your code in the call stack.

Comment: Use the call stack to find your code and you'll see where the error is.

Comment: I guess in general you could probably just look up a tutorial on how to use the Visual Studio debugger. There is much more to say about how to use a debugger than can be answered here.

Comment: Call stack can show the lines of error. But may not where the real problem is. If your problem is not resolved, please provide  a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the problematic place from the call stack. There you can go up and down the stack by double-clicking the corresponding line and check the *Autos* and *Locals* debugging windows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2022).

The problem you might have is that you are getting into the debugger too late, when the exception is unhandled (there were no try/catch blocks able to handle this, so it was caught by the C++ infrastructure). Check *Debug->Windows->Exception Settings* window and set the exception you get to break when the exception is thrown (not unhandled).

Comment: Thank you for the support. This is exactly what I asked for. Now I finally can resolve the problems much quicker.